# Running Karate from karate.jar with cucumber reports

Tags: karate

I want to run my karate tests using karate.jar.

Currently am using maven for execution. I have a runner class which handles cucumber reporting as mentioned in karate documentation.

java -jar karate.jar -T 5 -t ~@ignore -o /mydirectory/all.feature

When I change the test execution as above, is there a way I can get cucumber reports generated same as I was getting for maven?

my current execution is like this:  mvn clean test -Dtest=TestRunner.java -Dkarate.env=UAT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when running the features using [karate standalone](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar) jar, `cucumber-html-reports` will be generated default on `target` directory inside you `karate.jar`'s directory

look for `target\cucumber-html-reports` in the directory where you have you `karate.jar`

`java -jar karate.jar -T 5 -t ~@ignore /mydirectory/all.feature`

karate also provides a `-o` flag in which the provided directory will be used to save reports

`java -jar karate.jar -T 5 -t ~@ignore -o /mydirectory /mydirectory/all.feature`

Comment: I tried executing, but when I execute from jar, the  karate.config.js callOnce methods I wrote for authorization api and tokens are not being called. So none of my calls will fail. Do you know the reason?

Comment: I believe karate looks for karate-config.js in `classpath` in your case where you are having the jar. else you can pass the exact config file path as `java -Dkarate.config.dir=parentdir/somedir -jar karate.jar`

Comment: please read the doc: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#karate-configjs for more details

Comment: try updating to the latest version as well at least 0.9.5. I see there were some issues in older versions fixed later.

Comment: I am using latest 0.9.5 jar, looks like none of the calls i made to different files are happening, I get errors like classpath:src/test/resources/TestData/request.json not found.

Comment: As this question is related to cucumber reporting, please create a separate question with more details like your project folder structure etc.

Comment: Doing that now.

Comment: @RAKESHM before doing that, please see if it works fine in 0.9.6.RC3

Comment: @PeterThomas will i get a complete jar for 0.9.6RC3 to be downloaded?

Comment: @RAKESHM yes, see the "bintray" link: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: @PeterThomas thanks i downloaded and ran, same classpath issue am getting classpath:src/test/resources/TestData/request.json my jar and karate-config.js are both in same location inside src/test/java

Comment: @RAKESHM time for you to follow this process then: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue